# MDX - Query Attribute in the CrossJoin - Essbase

Tags: mdx, mdx-query, essbase

I currently have a CrossJoin working for UDA.  However we want to change to using Attribute value instead.  Not sure how to get the Syntax correct to use Attribute in the CrossJoin in Essbase. I commented out the UDA part which works great.  However the Attribute part isn't working.  Appreciate any guidance.

```
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin(
CrossJoin( 
CrossJoin(

{[AC_910006]},
{[EN_TotBevEMEAElim]}),

/*
{UDA([Customer].CurrentMember,\"EUR_Intra\")}),
*/

{Filter(Descendants([CU_Intra],Levels([Customer],0)),
            [Customer].CurrentMember.[IntraCoCust] = \"EUR_Intra\")}),


{Descendants([Orig_Entity],Levels([Orig_Entity],0))}),
{Descendants([Total_Sizes],Levels([Size],0))}),
{Descendants([Total_Types],Levels([Type],0))}),         
{[FC],[EUR],[USD]}),                                                                 
{[FY22]}),
{[Jul]:[Dec]})"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it correctly try

```
    Withattr ( [Customer], "==", "EUR_Intra" )
```

and for more than one attribute you can use the Intersect command.

```
    Intersect ( Withattr ( [Customer], "==", "EUR_Intra" ), Withattr ( [Customer], "==", "EUR_Extra" ) )
```

Here is a helpful link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/ESBTR/mdx_withattr.html

Steve